# Append XMLDocument to other

Tags: c#, .net

I have following two xml strings

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <AccessRequest xml:lang='en-US'>
    <AccessLicenseNumber>YOURACCESSLICENSENUMBER</AccessLicenseNumber>
    <UserId>YOURUSERID</UserId>
    <Password>YOURPASSWORD</Password>
  </AccessRequest>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<RatingServiceSelectionRequest>                            
<PickupType>
  <Code>01</Code>
</PickupType>
<Shipment>
  <Description>Rate </Description>
  <Shipper>
    <Address>
      <PostalCode>originzip</PostalCode>
    </Address>
</Shipper>
<ShipTo>
  <Address>
    <PostalCode>destinationzip</PostalCode>
    <CountryCode>countrycode</CountryCode>
  </Address>
</ShipTo>
<Service>
  <Code>11</Code>
</Service>
<Package>
  <PackagingType>
    <Code>02</Code>
    <Description>Package</Description>
  </PackagingType>
  <Description>Rate Shopping</Description>
  <PackageWeight>
    <Weight>weight</Weight>
  </PackageWeight>
</Package>
<ShipmentServiceOptions/>
</Shipment>
</RatingServiceSelectionRequest>
```

I want to append second xml string to first one. I tried writing both XmlDocuments to a XmlWriter. But it throws exception "Cannot write XML declaration. XML declaration can be only at the beginning of the document."

```
Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream();
XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();


doc1.LoadXml(xmlData1);
doc2.LoadXml(xmlData2);

XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
xws.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(stm, xws))
{
  doc1.WriteTo(xw);
  doc2.WriteTo(xw);
}
```

How can I append it as is? Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge two XmlDocuments in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440073/how-to-merge-two-xmldocuments-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You have a typo in 1st line `<?xmlversion="1.0"?>` ... no space between _xml_ and _version_ ?

Comment: @coder. thanks for pointing to typo in 1st line. I wrote it wrong  while posting question.

Comment: @Alberto I tried that. It adds second xml nodes starting from RatingServiceSelectionRequest to AccessRequest node. But I need it to be appended after AccessRequest node without losing <?xml version="1.0"?>.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` from second xml string before appending it to first xml string.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I can't remove <?xml version="1.0" ?> from second xml string. I know it is an invalid xml. But I need it as is to call UPS Rating api.

Comment: You can remove it from second string but then you can't use XML classes because they expect valid XML.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in the past. The two lines of code below did the job:

```
var MyDoc = XDocument.Load("File1.xml");
MyDoc.Root.Add(XDocument.Load("File2.xml").Root.Elements());
```

If you already have strings ready, then please use the `Parse` function instead of `Load`.

Please notice I am using the System.Xml.Linq that uses `XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument` class.

**EDIT**

As I understood, you need both documents to be concatenated as is. The problem is that it will eventually leads to an invalid XML document for two reasons :

- the document will contain *two* root nodes: `AccessRequest` and `RatingServiceSelectionRequest`. A valid XML document contains only *one* root node.
- There must be only one `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` XML declaration at the beginning of a document.

If the UPS api your are using is fed with an invalid XML, you unfortunately can not use XML objects. Therefore you will have to use a simple string concatenation to achieve what you want:

```
var xml = xmlData1 + xmlData2;
```

Comment: it appends second xml nodes starting from RatingServiceSelectionRequest to AccessRequest node. But I need it to be appended after AccessRequest.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry I missed that part. I'm afraid the solution I suggest will not please you :-/